# Rails - updating div w/ Ajax and :remote => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I've followed this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) on submitting a form via Ajax and updating a div without reloading the page, but I'm having trouble with one portion of it.

Ryan has `$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@products)) %>");` in an `index.js.erb` file to update the `#products` div when the form is submitted. I'm struggling to understand whether an instance variable like `@products` is relevant for my situation, or if I can simply substitute it for a URL.

I'm trying to do the same thing as Ryan in this screencast, but instead of display search results I just want to display the updated value.

**In show.html.erb I have:**

```
<% @project.project_todos.order("created_at DESC").where(:status => false).each do |todo|%>

<%= form_for todo, :remote => true, :"data-replace" => "#dueon" do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :due %>
   <%= f.submit :class => "primary", :value => "Add" %>
<% end %>

<div id="dueon">
   <%= render "duedate", :todo => todo %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

The partial `_duedate.html.erb` has one line in it: `<%= todo.due %>`

So in my index.js.erb I currently have this: `$("#dueon").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("_duedate")) %>");` but it's clearly not working. Do I have to use a variable here in place of the `_duedate`? And if so, how would I set this up in the controller? I mean what does the variable have represent?

Also, for what it's worth, the partial is rendering correctly and displaying the `todo.due` value...it's just not updating when I submit the form.

**ProjectsController:**

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    # Display the form to create a new todo
    @project_todo = ProjectTodo.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

in you controller action , (say sample_action)

```
def sample_action
   @todos = #your code

   respond_to do |format|
      format.js
   end
end
```

and you have a `sample_action.js.erb`

```
$("#dueon").html("<%= raw escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'duedate')) %>")
```

then inside the partial, you have access to the new `@todos` instance variable

HTH

Comment: I already have access to the @project.project_todos instead variable inside the partial by passing ```:todo => todo``` when I render the partial. Is that not sufficient? If not, then what would go inside the ```#your code``` comment? Something like ```ProjectTodos.all```? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @TrevanHetzel, could u post your controller action so that I could give you a better answer :)

Comment: For sure, I just updated the question with the show action of the ProjectsController.

Comment: Also, I should clarify that I'm displaying the form and values for the project_todos (it has its own model and belongs_to a project) inside the project's show view.

Comment: How would i submit this form to the action you wrote above and how to add this path to the routes file

Answer (score 0):

I will answer you separately as I believe your entire setup should be little change (IMO, this might not be the case)

I think you  should have a todos controller with a project belongs to it,

--- models ----------------

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos
end

class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :project
end
```

---- routes ---------------

```
resources :projects do
  resources :todos do
  end
end
```

---- controllers ----------

class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

end

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController

   def new
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @todos = @project.todos.build
   end
end
```

in your view (views/todos.html.erb)

```
<%= @project.name %>
<%= form_for([@Project, @todos]) do |f| %>
  #todo form code
<% end%>
```

As per the relation, project has many todos, its always clear to show the project details in the todo add screen, rather than allowing users to add new todos from project screen.

and again, this is my personal view, feel free to ask any questions :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't really want to change the whole associations around because of the way the application is set up. Todos are dependent on a project. You have to create a project, then add tasks to that project to complete. I appreciate you writing all that code though, but unfortunately I don' think I can switch my associations around at this point.

Comment: Ok :), then I think you approach is correct, just change the rendering format to js , instead of json, let me know it it works :D

Comment: I'm guessing I need to change the ```format.json { head :no_content }``` line in the ```update``` method of the ProjectTodos controller to ```format.js```? It's not working, so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Because see really what this form is doing is updating the :due attribute in the project_todo table. The ability to update this column is not available until the project todo is created. Maybe the due date should have its own controller, I don't know, but this is the way I'm currently doing it so hopefully I can make it work.

Comment: BTW, are u getting any ajax javascript errors, you could check it via firebug in FF, coz there are situation where protect_from_forgery command is blocking your way, check your client side ajax errors

Comment: Actually, yeah I am! Updated the question w/ the errors. They look like they're coming from the updating of the form though, which is working fine. It's just the reloading of the partial that I can't get to work.

Comment: probably that might casing the rending to halt, could u post those ajax errors you are getting

Comment: Yeah I posted them in your answer at the bottom

Comment: Also, is this the correct js I should be using to update the #dueon div? ```$("#dueon").html("<%= raw escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'duedate')) %>")```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21246/discussion-between-sameera207-and-trevan-hetzel)