# Update html page every X seconds using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I saw this post about this issue:
[Auto Refresh a Html table every x seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320234/auto-refresh-a-html-table-every-x-seconds)

Now, i am using rails, and i would like to do the same thing, but i want to tell rails that i want a remote page, i dont want it to load the full page.
All i want is pretty much to simulate :remote => true action with ajax.
I've tried it with regular ajax, and rails loads the whole page instead of just the relevant content that i want.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should be something like this:

`Your controller`

```
def your_action
 # your code goes here
end
```

`(your_action.js.erb)`

```
$("#div_id").html("<%= escape_javascript reder :partial => "your_partial_for_table" %>")
```

`your_action.html.erb`

```
<div id="div_id">
 <%= render :partial => "your_partial_for_table" %>
</div>
```

`_your_partial_for_table.html.erb`

```
#your table goes here

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "<path to your_action>",
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "script"
        });
      }, 30000); // In every 30 seconds
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @algorhythm: Hey actually it worked for me, give a try. I have used it for automatic notification display with each 30 seconds time interval.

Answer (score 2):

**Server Sent Events**

You may wish to use [Server Sent Events (from HTML5)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/):

> Server-sent events (SSE) is a technology for where a browser gets
>   automatic updates from a server via HTTP connection. The Server-Sent
>   Events EventSource API is standardized as part of HTML5[1](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) by the W3C.

This basically initiates something called [ajax long-polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery), which is where your JS will "ping" a particular URL every second, or number of seconds. 
The Ajax polling requests will then bring back particular response from the server, allowing you to use as you wish

--

**Layout**

I would do this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var source = new EventSource('path/to/your/endpoint');
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      //do something here
}, false);

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   include ActionController::Live

   def your_action
       response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'

       sse = Reloader::SSE.new(response.stream)
       begin
           sse.write(last_updated, event: 'results')
       rescue IOError
          # When the client disconnects, we'll get an IOError on write
       ensure
         sse.close
       end
   end
end
```

The trick here is that SSE's use their own content type - `text/event-stream` to receive & parse the required data. This is compared with the standard `mime` types which governs the typical HTTP protocol

[I used this url for reference](https://github.com/acdesouza/rails-and-server-sent-events/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb) - you can then manipulate the text as it comes back from the server!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* with jQuery */
jQuery(documenta).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('.table').load(...);
    , 5000);
});

# with rails, determine if it is a ajax request
if request.xhr?
    # respond to Ajax request
else
    # respond to normal request
end
```

see also here [Rails detect if request was AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220701/rails-detect-if-request-was-ajax)

Comment: Will rails know its a remote request ? thats what i saw in the other comment i posted, its not helping since it loads the whole page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Why should rails know if it is a remote request? Every request is a remote request, isn't it? You want to know, if it is an ajax request, right? See solution...

Comment: I mean that i want it to act just like a rails link with 
:remote => true

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909354/rails-updating-div-w-ajax-and-remote-true